# Multipart form/data uploading in ios

Tags: afnetworking, multipartform-data

```
<form method="post" action="upload.php?u=test&p=test" name="FrmUpload"  autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" onchange="document.forms[0].submit();"/>
</form>
```

The above code is working in html. I am trying to do in AFnetworking multipart audio file uploading: **This is my equivalent ios code:**

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"id":@"file"};

[[RequestOperationManager sharedManager] POST:@"my url string" parameters:dic
 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData){
        NSError *error = nil;

        [formData appendPartWithFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"my file path"] name:@"file" fileName:file mimeType:@"audio/aac" error:&error];

    }success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject){

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
            NSLog(@"%d : %@", error.code, error.description);
        }
    }];
```

It returns the error:

**Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.)**

Answer (score 0):

-(void)uploadAudio{
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] ***

initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"**http://server.url"**]];

---

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.avatarView.image, 0.5);
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": self.username, @"password" : self.password};
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [manager POST:@"rest.of.url" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    //do not put image inside parameters dictionary as I did, but append it!
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:paramNameForImage fileName:@"photo.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Success: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ ***** %@", operation.responseString, error);
}];
[op start];
```

}

i Think Some detail must be missing ... like ur url ......or key.....